# How to use anko spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, kotlin, anko

I'm trying to add a spinner inside an alert using anko. My code so far looks like this:

```
alert(getString(R.string.alert)) {
            positiveButton("Cool") { toast("Yess!!!") }
            customView {
                linearLayout {

                    textView("I'm a text")
                    padding = dip(16)
                    orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                    spinner(R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner) {
                        id = R.id.spinner_todo_category
                        prompt = "Select a Category"
                    }



                }
            }
        }.show()
```

but I get compilation errors because apparently that's not how to call a spinner. I've been looking at the docs ([Anko GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki)) but it says nothing about spinners.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this link may help you https://github.com/Kotlin/anko-example

Comment: I checked it but there's no example on how to use a spinner. @NileshRathod

Comment: check this link https://github.com/lightningkite/kotlin-anko/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lightningkite/kotlin/anko/HintSpinner.kt or this https://github.com/lightningkite/kotlin-anko

Answer (score 2):

One solution :

```
class AddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val items = listOf(Friend("bla","bla",50),Friend("bla","bla",50));

        val adapterFriends = ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.mon_spinner,items)

        verticalLayout {

            val friends = spinner {  adapter = adapterFriends  }

            val wine = editText()

            button("Say Hello") {
                onClick { toast("Hello, ${wine.text}!") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with this layout (mon_spinner.xml) :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:text="XXX"
    />
```

It's all right !!

Comment: As in the other answer: you could also use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` if you don't want to create a layout yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AnkoComponent:

```
spinner {
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            ctx,
            R.array.your_string_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
}
```